# Add properties to Azure Active Directory User "Work Info" tab

Tags: azure, entra-id

Within Azure Active Directory, if I create a new Active Directory and begin to manually add users, I have visibility of a number of fields:

[image]

However, there are way more tabs/fields on the server version of Active Directory.  I wondered if it was possible to enable some of these fields, e.g. Employee ID into Azure?

I read something about a "Graph API" being able to change Azure fields, but I don't have enough experience to realise whether this is the correct approach or not.  I started to read the online documentation but its way more complex than I'd hoped, so am looking for some clarity before I brave it.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: No**

**Details:**

[Azure AD is not AD DS in Azure.](http://windowsitpro.com/identity-management/windows-azure-active-directory-vs-windows-server-active-directory)
[image: Active Directory Venn Diagram]

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn720459.aspx) is the functionality currently available in the Graph API.  It allows *application-specific* schema extensions, enabling an application to store custom attributes in the directory.  These attributes are not accessible to other applications (or the portal) and cannot be synched with your on-premises directory.

The good news is that global schema extensions are supposedly on the roadmap: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/03/06/preview-release-of-custom-schema-extension-for-azure-ad.aspx

This article may also be of use: [Azure Active Directory for the Old-School AD Admin](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2015/01/05/azure-active-directory-for-the-old-school-ad-admin.aspx)

Comment: Good answer, thanks.  Just for clarity, if my app needs to read the *EmployeeID* field from an on-premise AD that is sync'd to our multi-tenant Azure AD, can this value be read by my application?  I appreciate that you have clarified that (at present) we cannot natively store it in the available fields in AAD.

Comment: If EmployeeID is not part of the standard AAD schema (I don't think it is but I'm not able to confirm right now) then you won't be able to sync it from your on-prem AD.

Comment: The Salesforce app appears to achieve it.  If you add it to Azure you can see all the extra fields they sync with from on-prem

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is "extend the schema" with your own attributes.

Graph API is the way to go, as discussed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn720459.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The old article for the preview release: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2014/03/06/extend-azure-active-directory-schema-using-graph-api-preview.aspx

Comment: Those schema extensions are specific to the application which creates them via the Graph API.